# How to GROUP BY whole table object in Oracle and JPA?

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa, group-by

I'm struggling with incompatible SQL statement between PostgreSQL and Oracle.

I made `SELECT` statement for PostgreSQL like below:

```sql
SELECT usr AS user, COUNT(bk) AS count
FROM user usr
    LEFT JOIN book bk ON usr.id = bk.user
GROUP BY usr;
```

This statement can be run on PostgreSQL DB without any problems. Unfortunately not in Oracle DB. I tried with multiple another statements, ex. `select usr.*` etc. but in Oracle it does not work.

It tells me every time that column `usr` cannot be resolved.

Is there any other way to select whole object (which could be correctly mapped by Hibernate later) together with `group by`? And is it possible to make this statement compatible with those 2 DB?

I'm looking for the approachment, which I've already made for Hibernate with PostgreSQL, so that statement would give me `Tuple<User, Long>`.

Comment: You need to use `usr.*` then list each and every column of the `user` table in the GROUP BY. There is no alternative shortcut in Oracle.

Comment: you cant group by usr, you can use gropu by urs.attribute_name. What are the attributes of tables user and book?

Comment: What exactly do you want to count there? From which table does the column `b` come from?

Comment: Sorry @a_horse_with_no_name , should be `count(bk)` and not `count(b)`, i fixed question

Comment: You could rewrite the query to do the count on just the book table, then left outer join that to the user table (and nvl the count result to 0 if no rows match)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the count of books per user, don't group the result of the join, but join to the result of a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT usr.*, coalesce(b.num_books, 0) as num_books
FROM user usr
  LEFT JOIN ( 
    select bk.user, count(*) as num_books
    from book bk
    group by bk.user
  ) b ON usr.id = b.user
```

That would be more efficient in Postgres as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it won't work with Hibernate then. With actual PostgreSQL statement I can convert result to Tuple of User entity and number of books (long). This Oracle statement above gives me all User cols + num_book count col which afaik cannot be converted to JPA Entity and count Touple. Probably, main problem is, that `usr.*` cannot be used with `AS user`.

Comment: Well, you should have told us that you are limited by the (non) features of an obfuscation layer. And the question should have been tagged with `jpa` + `oracle`. The `sql` tag is wrong if you don't want a SQL answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. I though, that main difference is laying mainly in SQL Statement and not JPA.

Comment: @Dawid: does JPA really not support such a basic SQL statement? That's even worse then I assumed

Comment: It does, but with this statement, I'm getting a number of columns which JPA cannot recognize, that first x columns is User entity Object and the last column is just an count of books.